# How to recovery EC2 using Cloudwatch alarm by StatusCheckFailed_Instance metric(Not StatusCehckFailed_System metric!!!)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudwatch-alarms

I looking for a solution that automatically recovery EC2 when the instance is failed Status check by OS error.

Frequently one of the instances failed status check because of OOM(Out of memory) by application or OOM by High disk IO, too high disk throughput.
If some instance got issues by OS error that indicates StatusCheckFailed_instance in CloudWatch Metric

Sometimes rebooting was not solved Failed Status check issues, need to stop and start the instance even StatusCheckFailed_instance.
But CloudWatch Alarm doesn't provide recovery(Stop and Start) action to the problem instance when a metric is StatusCheckFailed_instance... only provide when StatusCheckFailed_System.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/UsingAlarmActions.html#AddingRecoverActions

How automatic recovery problem instances when got StatusCheckFailed_instance????

Comment: If you are running out of RAM and disc space, why not get instance with more ram and space?

Comment: Because cost and instance spec is enough. Usually the instance use memory less than 30% for per month. But suddenly one of applications too use  memory...  I looking for why but not found cause yet.